# Is there any way to add a class attribute to an input tag generated by django.models?

Tags: python, css, django

I can't figure it out for the life of me. I don't think it's possible. Something so simple shouldn't be hard at all. Anyone?

Comment: Please clarify "input tag".  Please provide some example of what you're looking to do/create.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what you're referring to. Do you mean an HTML <input> tag generated by django.forms? If so, just specify a custom widget, using the attrs attribute in the constructor. See [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances).

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean. and i know about the attr object i can set. however, automatically generated forms from the django.models class doens't seem to allow for this.

Comment: To customize the widget, declare the field in your form class. You have to do so for each field you want to add a class attribute to. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types

Answer (score 3):

[django-html](http://github.com/simonw/django-html) provides a templatetag which allows you to add extra attributes in the template, like so:

```
{% field form.fieldname class="myclass" %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to override the relevant field in your form class, and add your attribute to the widget. This is described clearly [in the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types).

Comment: there is no form class. it's a model class.

Comment: You must have a form class somewhere, even if it only has the meta `class=MyModel` declaration. Or did you mean a form generated within the admin? If so, please say so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of these is particularly what the asker was looking for and now a few years after the question was posted this can be done much more intuitively. I think the asker wants the ModelForm field to render the input tag with a class attribute which you set in your view.

If so, the answer is here:

[How do I set default widget attributes for a Django ModelForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679431/how-do-i-set-default-widget-attributes-for-a-django-modelform)

Indeed, maybe this was the case even way back in 09, in which case the other answers should be downvoted. But I wasn't working with Django back then so I'll leave that to others.