# How to add an attribute to an option in a select form in django python

Tags: python, django

I have  models

```
class tipo_pago(models.Model):
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    banco_req   = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Requiere banco", help_text="Activa esta casilla si se requiere el banco de origen")
    status      = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

and

```
class cliente_pago(models.Model):
    tEstado = (
        ('pagado','Pagado'),
        ('pendiente','Pendiente'),
        ('cancelado','Cancelado'),
    )

    cliente     = models.ForeignKey('cliente',blank=False,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    fecha       = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    fecha_pago  = models.DateField()
    tipo_pago   = models.ForeignKey('tipo_pago',blank=False,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    banco       = models.ForeignKey('banco', blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    referencia  = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    cuenta      = models.ForeignKey('cuenta',blank=False,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    importe     = models.FloatField(default=0)
    pago        = models.FloatField(default=0)
    saldo       = models.FloatField(default=0)
    observacion = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    estado      = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='pendiente',choices=tEstado)
```

My form to fill the fileds is the next one:

```
class cliente_pagoModal(CustomModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model   = cliente_pago
        exclude = ('fecha','pago','saldo','estado',)
```

To the field `tipo_pago` in `cliente_pago` form i want to add a data parameter

Now look like this:

```
<select name="tipo_pago" class="form-control" required="" id="id_tipo_pago">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
  <option value="3">Efectivo</option>
  <option value="2">Cheque</option>
  <option value="1">Transferencia bancar</option>
</select>
```

but I want it to look like this

```
<select name="tipo_pago" class="form-control" required="" id="id_tipo_pago">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
  <option value="3" data-banco_req="0">Efectivo</option>
  <option value="2" data-banco_req="1">Cheque</option>
  <option value="1" data-banco_req="2">Transferencia bancar</option>
</select>
```

I am using python 3.7 and django 2.0.8

Comment: Answer on below link could work for your case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43736976/7235253

Comment: If not that, you can define widget option in the Meta class of the model form. Simply add custom attrs there.

Comment: Some examples are given in below link

Comment: https://www.webforefront.com/django/modelforms.html

Comment: There is a general solution which works for Django 2.+ and allows to add a title and other things in options, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56097149/1788851

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `data-banco_req` is a count of the loops, you can build the `select` element in your template and iterate over the choices:

```
{% with field=form.tipo_pago %}
<label for="{{ field.auto_id }}">{{ field.label }}</label> 
<select name="{{ field.html_name }}" class="form-control" required="" id="{{ field.id_for_label }}">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
  {% for choice in field %}
  <option value="{{ choice.data.value }}" data-banco_req="{{ forloop.counter0 }}">{{ choice.choice_label }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: I understand, the point is that I need to take data value from the field's model

Comment: I understand, the point is that I need to take data value from the field's model, and from the file "forms.py".

I wanted to find an automatized way to solve this and not to draw the code in my modal

Comment: The `banco_req` field on the `tipo_pago` model is a `BooleanField`. Where do the numbers 0, 1, 2 come from?

Comment: It was a typo mistake

Comment: OK. You have said "To the field "tipo_pago" in cliente_pago form i want to add a data parameter". Where will the values in the data parameter come from? Which field on which model?